# Java program will compile but not run

Tags: java

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

I have defined my interface as:

```
interface Model 
{
public String  toString();
public Model add (Model m);
}
```

There are 2 classes implementing the interface (ClassA and ClassB):

```
class ClassA implements Model
{
private int val;

public ClassA(int x) 
{
    val = x;
}

public String toString() 
{
 return ""+ "value of object of class A is " + val;
}

public Model add (Model m) 
{
 if (m instanceof ClassA)
   return new ClassA(val + ( (ClassA) m).val);
 else
   return null;
}
}

class ClassB implements Model 
{

private String str;

public  ClassB(String s)
{
 str = s;
}

public String toString()
{
 return str;
 }

 public Model add (Model m) 
 {
 if (m instanceof ClassB)                      
 return new ClassB(str + ((ClassB) m).str); 
 else
 return null;
 }
 }
```

My main defines objects of ClassA and ClassB and calls their tostring() methods.

```
public class Example {
public static void main (String args[]) {
 ClassA a = new ClassA(5);
 ClassB b= new ClassB("Hi");

 Model m = b;
 System.out.println(m.toString());

 ClassA a1 = new ClassA(7);

 m = a.add(a1);

 System.out.println(m);
}
}
```

When I try to build this file it compiles fine but, upon trying to run the application I get an error message:

"Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
(to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
(to execute a jar file).....etc...etc"

Can anyone help me with this? It's probably something simple. I'm a beginner Java student.

Comment: What may be most important is what you're not showing us. How are you trying to run this program?

Comment: What command are you typing when you try to run your program? What command did you use to compile it?

Comment: Can you write the command you launch when you try run the application?

Comment: I am using JCreator and clicking on the "run file" option after building file.

Comment: Trying compiling and running it in terminal or command prompt with `javac Example.java` to compile and `java Example` to run it. Then tell us what happens. (Make sure you are in the right directory)

Comment: Since you're a beginner, you might as well learn this upfront: most programs compile but don't run correctly ;-)

Comment: @user, if your IDE is spitting that error back out to you, then at least in some ways, it is not in fact "[more reliable than other Java IDE’s.](http://www.jcreator.com/)".  No user mistake should produce this error message in an IDE, so unfortunately it's a bug and it's generating your command line incorrectly.

Comment: I just checked my version of Java and realized it was out of date. After I updated to the most recent version the application ran fine. Thanks for all of your input...

Comment: On that basis, I'm voting to close as "too localized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your program.Your program is absolutely ok. But , I do not know which command you are writing for execution .Try once again with absolute path setting to JDK and JRE.

Command like:-

for Compile `-javac Example.java`
for Run `-java Example`

It will successfully run. Hope it will help you.